# 'Image' has no propType for native prop 'RCTImageView.overlayColor' of native type 'number'

Tags: javascript, java, android, ios, react-native

Hello I am trying to run my react native app on android and I am getting this error message.  The app has been working on iOS for months and this is the first time we are trying to use it on android.  We are using react-native .19.  I have tried restarting the packager multiple times as well as restarting Android Studio and it has not helped at all.  I have also removed my entire node_modules folder and reinstalled everything and the error still exists

`'Image' has no propType for native prop 'RCTImageView.overlayColor' of native type 'number'`

Settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'MassTuning'

include ':app'
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons//Users/kvieira/code/masstuning/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
include ':react-native-linear-gradient'
project(':react-native-linear-gradient').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/android')
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/android')
include ':react-native-image-picker'
project(':react-native-image-picker').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker/android')
include ':react-native-mail'
project(':react-native-mail').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-mail/android')
include ':react-native-admob'
project(':react-native-admob').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-admob/android')
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers two tasks: bundleDebugJsAndAssets and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets.
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"]
 * ]
 */

apply from: "react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create three separate APKs instead of one:
     *   - A universal APK that works on all devices
     *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
     *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
     * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
     * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
     * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
     */
    def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

    /**
     * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
     */
    def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.masstuning"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
            }
        }
        splits {
            abi {
                enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
                universalApk true
                reset()
                include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            }
        }
        // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
                // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
                def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
                def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
                if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                    output.versionCodeOverride =
                            versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
                }
            }
        }
    }

    configurations.all {
      resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'


}
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-admob')
    compile project(':react-native-mail')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.19.+"

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.masstuning;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.sbugert.rnadmob.RNAdMobPackage;
import com.chirag.RNMail.RNMail;
import com.imagepicker.ImagePickerPackage;
import com.AirMaps.AirPackage;
import com.BV.LinearGradient.LinearGradientPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "MassTuning";
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether dev mode should be enabled.
     * This enables e.g. the dev menu.
     */
    @Override
    protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
        return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

   /**
   * A list of packages used by the app. If the app uses additional views
   * or modules besides the default ones, add more packages here.
   */
    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        new MainReactPackage(),
        new RNAdMobPackage(),
        new RNMail(),
        new ImagePickerPackage(),
        new AirPackage(),
        new LinearGradientPackage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Got solution to this issue?

Comment: I upgradeded to react native 20 and this issue was gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by upgrading react to 20.  After that I never saw this issue again